# Userform makes Excel crash depending on condition

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm facing a funny issue I don't understand.

In VBA, I want to load a Userform when the user double click on a cell, depending on the cell content. But depending on the condition I ask, Excel will crash once I exit the Sub (it keeps executing code even after the UserForm is closed).

This works:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myForm As New UserForm1
    If Target.Cells(1).Value = "" Then
        myForm.Show
    End If
    Debug.Print ("OK")
End Sub
```

And these three make Excel crash:

1.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myForm As New UserForm1
    If Target.Cells(1).Value <> "" Then
        myForm.Show
    End If
    Debug.Print ("OK")
End Sub
```

2.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myForm As New UserForm1
    If Not Target.Cells(1).Value = "" Then
        myForm.Show
    End If
    Debug.Print ("OK")
End Sub
```

3.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim myForm As New UserForm1
    If Target.Cells(1).Value = "Test" Then
        myForm.Show
    End If
    Debug.Print ("OK")
End Sub
```

I'm using an empty UserForm for testing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167937/discussion-on-question-by-svatik-userform-makes-excel-crash-depending-on-conditi).

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the code within your If block so that it does a `Cancel = True` to ignore the double-click action and also loads the form beforehand, like so:

```
If Target.Cells(1).Value = "Test" Then
    Cancel = True
    Load myForm
    myForm.Show
End If
```

Comment: `Load myForm` would be superfluous, since `myForm` is an object variable, auto-instantiated at that.

Comment: ...I'm not sure how that would make a difference on the OP's computer but not two other people that tested the same code?

Answer (score 1):

[Cancelling the cell edit mode entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557480/1188513) seems a pretty good way to limit the number of things that can go wrong.

There's more though.

```
Dim myForm As New UserForm1
```

That's creating an *auto-instantiated* `UserForm1` object in local scope. Since `Dim` statements aren't executable, that means regardless of whether you `Show` the form or not, the object will be created as soon as the procedure scope is entered.

You can easily avoid creating that object unconditionally, and even avoid the need to declare a variable for it, using a `With` block:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Cells(1).Value = "Test" Then
        Cancel = True
        With New UserForm1
            .Show
        End With
    End If
    Debug.Print "OK"
End Sub
```

That way the form instance only ever gets created if it needs to. Big huge kudos for avoiding the *default instance* trap though - you can read more about that [on my blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

Notice I also removed the extraneous parentheses around the `Debug.Print` argument list. Parentheses are actually actively harmful in procedure calls; you'll run into compile errors when you use them with multiple-parameter procedures, run-time errors when you need to pass an object reference, and logical bugs when you mean to pass a parameter `ByRef` - the parentheses used like this, are forcing VBA to evaluate the expression *as a value*, and always pass the result `ByVal`, regardless of whether the called procedure says it's taking a `ByRef` parameter.

Use parentheses when you're calling a *function* and capturing its return value in a local variable.

Comment: I didn't know I could instantiate and create Object directly in a With block. I'll try to use this when applicable from now on. Thank you for the details about the use of parentheses.

Comment: @Svatik alternatively you could separate the `Dim` and the `New`, by declaring the local variable `Dim myForm As UserForm1`, and then doing `Set myForm = New UserForm1` inside the conditional block. Though, I like how `With New` holds the object instance and ensures its proper destruction (NEVER goto-jump in/out of a `With` block!)

Comment: As for the `As New` implications, try doing `Dim foo As New UserForm1`, then do `Set foo = Nothing`, and then `Debug.Print foo Is Nothing` - compare expectation vs actual ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand that last part. Does it mean the Object isn't destroyed even if I affect Nothing to it ? Or is it instantiated again when i use it in Debug.Print ?

Comment: When you do `Dim foo As New Something`, VBA ensures that `foo` is a valid instance of `Something` throughout the scope it's declared in, *no matter what*. In the case of a `UserForm`, this can mean user clicks the red "X" to close the form, object gets destroyed along with its state (assuming you're not handling `QueryClose`), and then when the calling code queries the form's state (e.g. some property, or checkbox state), what it's reading is whatever the default state is, because it's not looking at the same object, rather a respawned-on-the-spot one: VBA recreates the object as needed.